# exception has been thrown by the target invocation microsoft.ria.client.targets(303 5)

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-5.0

I am using Visual studio 2013 professional for silverlight 5 application.
When I build the solution I got the below exception 
      **"exception has been thrown by the target invocation"** 
IN the output window I saw the issue with 
      **"microsoft.ria.client.targets(303 5)"**

The meesage is 
"C:\Program files(x86) \MSBuild \Microsoft \Silverlight \v5.0 \Microsoft.Ria.client.targets(303,5) : error : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation .".

This exceptions is pointing to 2 places, one is edmx file and other is microsoft.ria.client.targets. 
When I checked with the other colleague, same code is working fine in that machine. I am the only one facing this problem. I tried with copying that code to my machine and still getting the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with open ria client which is based on ria services when I tried run project on team city build agent.

1. I used .NET 4 and Microsoft.Bcl.Async so the first step I took was install/updated this package for all dependent projects. Next I set all assembly rebinding for Bcl package.
2. Install Silverlight Developer Runtime
3. Make sure you have added all the .config files like ConnectionString for projects with .edmx files. For build agent I had to copy these files manually

This error will be related to: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/662780/exception-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-in-microsoft-ria-client-targets